# Issue with Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS Policy (Python/Angular)

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, angular, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I am getting the following issue on Angular application, which is currently live on the web.
Users can't log in because of this. And, already logged in users can't use the website properly.

Error: **Access to XMLHttpRequest at "Frontend (Domain)" from origin "Backend (Domain)" has been blocked by CORS Policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I already seen many posts related to the same issue. Already implemented most of the solutions to the application. Let me explain in detail.

Application Details :
**Frontend:** Angular 7, SSL Installed.
**Backend:** Python 3.7, Django Rest framework, 'CorsHeader' Plugin installed, CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL is True and 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' is at the top of the middleware list.
**Apache on Server:** 'rewrite', 'wsgi' and 'headers' enabled.

**Most Importantly:** After implementing the solutions, the errors are gone for a while. But, after a few days/weeks, the same error occurs again. Rebooting the server will fix the issue. But, the same will come again after a few days/weeks.

What is the proper fix for this issue? Or Am I doing anything wrong on my side?

[image: Console log of Angular Application]

NB: I am not testing from local/postman. Everything works perfectly on local and Postman.

Adding two screenshots of a request. This request is done two times automatically. The first Request has no response. And, the Second request has a 503 response.

[image: Request with No Response]

[image: Resquest with 503 Response]

Comment: When you get that CORS error, what’s the HTTP code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Already checked. The response is an error.

Comment: If the response is an error, than it’s normal and expected that it won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin. In particular it’s expected with Apache Web Server. By default, the header will only get included in 2xx success responses — but not in error responses. So what’s described in the problem isn’t an indication of CORS problem. It seems like instead what needs to be fixed is whatever is causing the server to respond with an error to begin with. But to be clear, the CORS configuration isn’t causing that error; instead it’s the other way around.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Any Idea? I am out of ideas.

Comment: What do the server-side logs for that Apache/Python/Django server show? If you’re getting an error response, it would seem that some messages must be getting logged into server logs to indicate what problem is happening which ends up causing the server to send an error response. It could be anything — maybe the server process has a memory leak and ends up running out of memory, or maybe some other problem’s happening that causes it to end up getting wedged in some way. Whatever it is, the server logs would be the place to look next for some clues, I think.

Comment: I too facing same issue, any solution?

Comment: @Shakthifuture We still have the same problem.

Comment: @JintoAntony, I given answer Check and let me know whether it's working or not

Comment: @Shakthifuture No. it's not working

Comment: Post your interceptor code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root issue, please see your screenshot, there is `Access-Control-Request-Method: GET` and it should not be there.

[image]

In your angular code **remove** the below code.

```
request.headers
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Hope it resolve your issue.